# Moving a UI element with an object on-screen [Gamemaker]

Tags: game-maker

I have an `oPlayer`object, and an `oTutorial` object which has a DrawGUI event for displaying text on-screen.

Currently I have the text appearing at the top-left of the screen, but I would like the text to follow the `oPlayer` object around the room.

I have tried to set the x & y values in the DrawGUI event to the player's , but this does not have the desired effect; I imagine because the DrawGUI event doesn't occur every step.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want draw text in `Draw GUI` event, just add `Draw GUI` event to the player and place code like this:

```
var posx = x - view_xview[0];
var posy = y - view_yview[0];
draw_text(posx, posy, "Your text");
```

`Draw GUI` occur every step, like any other Draw's event. And GUI layer has independent resolution and coords (see functions `display_set_gui_size` and `display_set_gui_maximise`).